# How can a sum converge if it has a singularity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem 32 on page 630 in Larson Calculus 9e.

> In Exercies 29-36, test for convergence or divergence, using each test at least one. Identify which test was used.
>   $$32. \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} $$

when $n=2$ $a_2 = \frac{1}{2^3-8} = \frac{1}{0}$  Uh, not possible to divide by zero.

I know it converges for $\sum \limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} = -\dfrac{1}{3}$

### But what is **Undefined**$+-\frac{1}{3} = $ ????

From the comments, it is very likely a typo.

Thus, I will present some problems for more clearity.

$$ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} = -\dfrac{1}{3}$$ Will not converge because at $n = 2$ there is singularity?

Aka, No series can converge if there exist a singularity?

Comment: looks like a typo

Comment: I second the typo.

Comment: I third the typo.

Comment: I eight the typo, it was tasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as many pointed out, it seems like a typo.

Regarding:

> Thus, I will present some problems for more clearity.
>
> $$ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} = -\dfrac{1}{3}$$ Will not converge because at $n = 2$ there is singularity?
>
> Aka, No series can converge if there exist a singularity?

Notice that

$$ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} = -\dfrac{1}{3}$$

is just a (no sense) formula, so it cannot converge or diverge.

The question

> Does
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$$
>
> converge?

It's a shorthand for

> Does the sequence
>
> $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$
>
> converge?

In this case

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k^3-8}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

doesn't even makes sense, you have already noted why, so it can't converge nor diverge.

Comment: Nice answer.  I said that $\sum \limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3-8} = -\dfrac{1}{3}$ $n$ starting at 3 sums to -1/3 by wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum+%5Climits_%7Bn%3D3%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E3-8%7D.